# Hide file path and name references from editor`s bar of VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

After search into VSCode workbench api/references, I didnt find some way to **hide** the file name/path status bar of the editor.

**Did anyone succeed?**

[image: vscode editor settings.json]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open settings.json file and add the following:

```
"workbench.editor.showTabs": true,
```

You can open the settings.json file by clicking on Preferences -> Settings -> Edit in settings.json file. or by Command + shift + p and search for "Open Settings (JSON)".

Comment: How would this hide the name of the file? Isn't this related to the windows being shown as tabs?

Answer (score 1):

Look at this setting:

> Workbench › Editor: Label Format
>
> Controls the format of the label for an editor.

But `default` is the default and it only shows the filename - perhaps your setting got changed.

Comment: I did `"workbench.editor.labelFormat": "short"`. Better, but not the solution I am looking for. I would like something like "hide" or "none".

Comment: @calebeaires if you remove this setting and set "workbench.editor.showTabs" to false, then the path won't be visible, only the filename would.